# Can't use vim-surround with IdeaVim

Tags: plugins, rider, ideavim

iv started using IdeaVim as Plugin for Rider.
Everything is working fine except using vim-surround.
The corresponding github page states vim-surround should be emulated.
https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim

When i press cs{ the cursor behaves like: nothing, nothing, jump to former paragraph.

Does anyone have an intention on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did this actually work for you? Setting `set surround` in the config file doesn't seem to switch it on for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually enable emulated ideavim plugins in your `~/.ideavimrc`. You can enable vim-surround with

```
set surround
```

and in general, you can refer to the [docs for emulated plugins](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/doc/emulated-plugins.md).